# I have a script that performs an arithmetic function. I'd like for the script to refresh itself when I enter new numbers

Tags: powershell

My script takes in 3 number inputs and performs functions accordingly. For now I need to stop the entire script and re-run if I have new numbers to input. How can I use the same session to enter new numbers?

```
Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
$main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

# Box size
$main_form.Text ='ABC Pattern Calculator'
$main_form.Width = 450
$main_form.Height = 350
$main_form.AutoSize = $true

# Label1
$intitalLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$intitalLabel.Text = "Click on Bull or Bear tab"
$intitalLabel.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(30,20)
$intitalLabel.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$intitalLabel.AutoSize = $true
$main_form.Controls.Add($intitalLabel)


############################# TABS #######################################
 
# Tab master control
$MainTab = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
$MainTab.Size = '400,250'
$MainTab.Location = '30,50'
$MainTab.Multiline = $true
$MainTab.AutoSize = $true
$MainTab.Anchor = 'Top,Left,Bottom,Right'
 
# Tab pages
$TabPage1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$Tabpage1.TabIndex = 1
$Tabpage1.Text = 'Bullish Pattern'
$TabPage1.Name = 'Tab1'
 
$TabPage2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$Tabpage2.TabIndex = 2
$Tabpage2.Text = 'Bearish Pattern'
$TabPage2.Name = 'Tab2'


# Add tabs to tab control
$MainTab.Controls.AddRange(@($TabPage1,$TabPage2))
$main_form.controls.Add($MainTab)


########################## Bull Tab #######################################


# Textbox = Point A
$aBullTextbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$aBullTextbox.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(82,30)
$aBullTextbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140)
$main_form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$main_form.Controls.Add($aBullTextbox)


# Textbox = Point B
$bBullTextbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$bBullTextbox.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(82,80)
$bBullTextbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140)
$main_form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$main_form.Controls.Add($bBullTextbox)


# Textbox = Point C
$cBullTextbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$cBullTextbox.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(82,136)
$cBullTextbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140)
$main_form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$main_form.Controls.Add($cBullTextbox)


# Label1
$aBullLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$aBullLabel.Text = "A Low:"
$aBullLabel.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,30)
$aBullLabel.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$aBullLabel.AutoSize = $true
$main_form.Controls.Add($aBullLabel)


# Label2
$bBullLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$bBullLabel.Text = "B High:"
$bBullLabel.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,80)
$bBullLabel.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$bBullLabel.AutoSize = $true
$main_form.Controls.Add($bBullLabel)


# Label3
$cBullLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$cBullLabel.Text = "C Low:"
$cBullLabel.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,136)
$cBullLabel.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$cBullLabel.AutoSize = $true
$main_form.Controls.Add($cBullLabel)


# Radio button = Calculate
$bullCalculateButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$bullCalculateButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,180)
$bullCalculateButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,23)
$bullCalculateButton.Text = "Calculate"
$main_form.Controls.Add($bullCalculateButton)


# Math function
$bullCalculateButton.Add_Click({
    $aBullCalc = $aBullTextbox.Text
    $bBullCalc = $bBullTextbox.Text
    $cBullCalc = $cBullTextbox.Text

    $pointD = $bBullCalc - $aBullCalc + $cBullCalc

    # D Label
    $dBullLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $dBullLabel.Text = "Point D will be at:"
    $dBullLabel.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(230,50)
    $dBullLabel.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
    $dBullLabel.AutoSize = $true
    $main_form.Controls.Add($dBullLabel)

    # Answer to D
    $dcalcLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $dcalcLabel.Text = $pointD
    $dcalcLabel.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(280,70)
    $dcalcLabel.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
    $dcalcLabel.AutoSize = $true
    $main_form.Controls.Add($dcalcLabel)

    $TabPage1.Controls.AddRange(@($dcalcLabel,$dBullLabel))
})


$TabPage1.Controls.AddRange(@($aBullTextbox,$bBullTextbox,$cBullTextbox,$aBullLabel,$bBullLabel,$cBullLabel,$bullCalculateButton))


########################## Bear Tab #######################################


# Textbox = Point A
$aBearTextbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$aBearTextbox.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(82,30)
$aBearTextbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140)
$main_form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$main_form.Controls.Add($aBearTextbox)


# Textbox = Point B
$bBearTextbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$bBearTextbox.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(82,80)
$bBearTextbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140)
$main_form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$main_form.Controls.Add($bBearTextbox)


# Textbox = Point C
$cBearTextbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$cBearTextbox.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(82,136)
$cBearTextbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140)
$main_form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$main_form.Controls.Add($cBearTextbox)



# Label1
$aBearLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$aBearLabel.Text = "A High:"
$aBearLabel.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,30)
$aBearLabel.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$aBearLabel.AutoSize = $true
$main_form.Controls.Add($aBearLabel)


# Label2
$bBearLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$bBearLabel.Text = "B Low:"
$bBearLabel.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,80)
$bBearLabel.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$bBearLabel.AutoSize = $true
$main_form.Controls.Add($bBearLabel)


# Label3
$cBearLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$cBearLabel.Text = "C High:"
$cBearLabel.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,136)
$cBearLabel.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$cBearLabel.AutoSize = $true
$main_form.Controls.Add($cBearLabel)


# Radio button = Calculate
$BearCalculateButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$BearCalculateButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,180)
$BearCalculateButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,23)
$BearCalculateButton.Text = "Calculate"
$main_form.Controls.Add($BearCalculateButton)


# Math function
$BearCalculateButton.Add_Click({
    $aBearCalc = $aBearTextbox.Text
    $bBearCalc = $bBearTextbox.Text
    $cBearCalc = $cBearTextbox.Text

    $pointDbear = $aBearCalc - $bBearCalc - $cBearCalc

    # D Label
    $dbearLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $dbearLabel.Text = "Point D will be at:"
    $dbearLabel.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(230,50)
    $dbearLabel.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
    $dbearLabel.AutoSize = $true
    $main_form.Controls.Add($dbearLabel)

    # Answer to D
    $dbearcalcLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $dbearcalcLabel.Text = $pointDbear
    $dbearcalcLabel.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(280,70)
    $dbearcalcLabel.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
    $dbearcalcLabel.AutoSize = $true
    $main_form.Controls.Add($dbearcalcLabel)

    $TabPage2.Controls.AddRange(@($dbearcalcLabel,$dbearLabel))
})

$TabPage2.Controls.AddRange(@($aBearTextbox,$bBearTextbox,$cBearTextbox,$aBearLabel,$bBearLabel,$cBearLabel,$BearCalculateButton))

# To show the box
$main_form.ShowDialog()
```

My script takes in 3 number inputs and performs functions accordingly. For now I need to stop the entire script and re-run if I have new numbers to input. How can I use the same session to enter new numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify it by adding the labels to the main Form **only once** outside the `.Add_Click` event, then inside the event you can do your calculation and update their `.Text` property. This example demonstrates how to do it for the "Bullish Pattern" tab and you can do the same, following this example, for the "Bearish Pattern" one:

```bash
# Both labels are now outside the Event!

$dBullLabel = [Windows.Forms.Label]@{
    Text      = ''
    Location  = [Drawing.Point]::new(230, 50)
    Font      = [Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, [Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
    AutoSize  = $true
}

$dcalcLabel = [Windows.Forms.Label]@{
    Text     = ''
    Location = [Drawing.Point]::new(280, 70)
    Font     = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, [Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
    AutoSize = $true
}

$main_form.Controls.AddRange(@($dBullLabel, $dcalcLabel))
$TabPage1.Controls.AddRange(@($dcalcLabel, $dBullLabel))

$bullCalculateButton.Add_Click({
    # Inside the event, we do just calculation
    $pointD = [double] $aBullTextbox.Text - $bBullTextbox.Text - $cBullTextbox.Text
    # and update
    $dBullLabel.Text = "Point D will be at:"
    $dcalcLabel.Text = $pointD
})
```

[image: demo]